# htaccess redirect + rewrite for same URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL mydomain.com/abc/xyz
and I want to redirect it to mydomain.com/def

Now, I also want to rewrite mydomain.com/abc/xyz URL to mydomain.com/def that means if someone opens mydomain.com/def it should open the content of mydomain.com/abc/xyz

I have tried both the redirection and the rewriting and they both work individually, but not combined.

Here's the code

```
RewriteRule ^abc/xyz/ http://mydomain. com/def [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/def /abc/xyz  [NC,L]
```

In simple words lets consider URL1 = mydomain.com/abc/xyz
and URL2 = mydomain.com/def

I want URL2 as pretty URL and should open content of URL1
But if someone opens URL1, I want them to be redirected to URL2 and show the content of URL1

So, first redirect and then show content using rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if that rewriting rule *really* works separately... You say you are using a ".htaccess" file, so a distributed configuration file. When implementing rewriting rules in such location (as opposed to the central configuration of the http server) the matching pattern in rewrite rules is applied to a *relative* path. That actually makes a lot of sense if you think about it and it is clearly documented. That means that your matching pattern would never match ...

Here is a slightly modified version that works likewise, whether you implement those rules in a distributed or a central configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?abc/xyz/ https://example.com/def [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?def /abc/xyz  [NC,L]
```

And most likely you also want to be a bit more precise:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?abc/xyz/?$ https://example.com/def [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?def/?$ /abc/xyz  [NC,L]
```